# dynamic setOnCLickListener

Tags: android, listener, imagebutton

I'm using a table layout with rows that comes from an SQLite database, so I add the rows dynamically adding views to a row. Now, I added and `imageButton` in each row that handle the row edition and other that add it to the SQLite database. I would like if I go for the right path, so if there is a way to add a `SetOnClickListener` to each generated `imageButton`?

Comment: You doing it all wrong (in prev quetion i saw that youre using table layout and populate rows from db)   ... For stuff like this use ListView and adapter... Onitemclick method is there already... Use google and search listview + sqlite db sample

Comment: It was a thought if is possible to change the list view to have tables for more columns, I have a custom listView with the DB that is used for other data on the same app. The idea was to have something like phpMyadmin rows in a window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this code for adding click events for dynamically generated button

```
for (int position=0; position < parseInt; position++)
        {
            TableRow tableRow= new TableRow(this);

            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(006400);
//          ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);


            TextView idText = new TextView(this);
            idText.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));
            idText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            idText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            idText.setWidth(10);
            idText.setHeight(30);
            idText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbg);
//          idText.setPadding(0, 0, 1,0);

             tableRow.addView(idText);



            //THE CLICK EVENT OF BUTTON
            Button  textOne = new Button(this);
            textOne.setText("CLUB");
            textOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbg);
            textOne.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textOne.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);//left top right bottom
//          textOne.setPadding(2, 1, 1,0);
//          textOne.setB;

            textOne.setWidth(10);
            textOne.setHeight(30);

            textOne.setId(1+position);
            tableRow.addView(textOne);


//          textOne.setOnClickListener(this);

             textOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  // do something when the button is clicked

                    final Button button = (Button) arg0;



 System.out.println("button is clicked");



                });
```

Comment: thanks for the Idea but if I don't now how many buttons I have to create, because it depends on the DB rows number, I don't have dynamic listener, that is that I was looking for. By the way I decided that is to much work do it this way... I already put a list view with a cursorAdapter, and a onitemclick to manage a little option menu.